# php header function is not working in form data receiving page

Tags: php, database

After submitting form its receiving on same page & after inserting into database its execute header function. But header function is not working. here is my code:

```
if ($err == null && isset($_POST['regsignup']) == 'Register' ) {
  $user->addUser();
  #its the data inserting function on database
  header("location:login.php?register=true");
}
```

My addUser() functions as following:

```
public function addUser(){

        $user = new Users();

if(isset($_POST['regsignup']) && $_POST['regsignup'] == 'Register' ){
 $user->setUserEmail($_POST['regemail']);
$user->setUserPassword($_POST['regpass']);
$user->setUserFname($_POST['regfname']);
$user->setUserLname($_POST['reglname']);
$user->setUserPhoneno($_POST['regcell']);
}

          $dbconn = new DbConn();
          $db = $dbconn->getDB(); 

          $user_email = $user->getUserEmail();
          $user_pass = $user->getUserPassword();
          $user_fname = $user->getUserFname();
          $user_lname = $user->getUserLname();
          $user_cell = $user->getUserPhoneno();

           $sql = "insert into users (user_password, user_fname, user_lname, user_phoneno, user_email) values('$user_pass','$user_fname','$user_lname','$user_cell','$user_email')";
           $r = $db->exec($sql);

         return $r;

}
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: if you're receiving some error like "Headers already sent......" then write _ob_start()_ at the first line of your script

Comment: I am not getting any error, only it remains the same page @SureshKamrushi

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there must not be white spaces or any html printed before you send the headers. 
And try using Capital "L" like below :

```
header("Location: login.php?register=true");
```

For more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_start();
```

at first line in your php code

Correct your headers

Should be

```
header("Location: login.php?register=true");
```

Answer (score 0):

This block will never execute.

```
if ($err == null && isset($_POST['regsignup']) == 'Register' ) {
    $user->addUser();
    #its the data inserting function on database
    header("location:login.php?register=true");
}
```

This block will

```
if ($err === null && isset($_POST['regsignup']) && $_POST['regsignup'] === 'Register' ) {
    $user->addUser();
    #its the data inserting function on database
    header("location:login.php?register=true");
}
```

The points to make, **isset()** returns a true or false boolean it does not return a string, so **isset($var) == 'some string'** will not execute unless that string happens to be 1 or 0, yes/no, true/false.

Now note also my **===**

This says match by value AND typecast EG: string in your case. So, first you check the value is set, then you check the value is correct and it of of the typecast you expect.